# Write typoscript in project files and not in backend

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

Okay the title may be confusing and thats because im a beginner in typo3.

So i set up a empty typo3 project via composer.

Now i want to write my typoscript "code" in my project files and not directley in the backend.

I added a template to a page and in the setup i started to define some page objects.

My problem is:

How do i tell typo3 to use the code that i write in my files rather then the code that is in the backend.
Also where should i put my typoscrip files.
I have them like this.

Also im a bit confused on why my ext directory is empty (besides what i added)

[image: Folder Structure here]

So i would like to move this code

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page {
  bodyTag = <body>
  meta.AUTHOR = My Name
  meta.DESCRIPTION = My Website
}
```

To my Project file, and not do any editing in the backend.

Thank you this is my first time posting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your project extension (let it call sitepackage) is missing some files. At least an ExtensionManager configuration file **ext_emconf.php** in the root of your extension 'typo3conf/ext/website' and for composer based TYPO3 installation also a Composer configuration **composer.json**. See documentation here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/ExtensionConfiguration/Index.html#directory-and-file-structure

To get started with your own sitepackagae extension have a look at 
https://sitepackagebuilder.com/ which helps to kickstart. It will create folder and files, which you may not need, but gives you an impression, which is best practice for file and folders inside your TYPO3 extension.

In your Installation you need to create a root template at your root page. See documentation here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TemplatingTutorial/7.6/Tasks/WorkingTypoScript/TypoScriptTemplate/Index.html#create-a-new-typoscript-template

Your sitepackage extension should includes TypoScript files under **Configuration/TypoScript/**, which you can include manually in root TypoScript template at your root page.

for constants

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT:source="FILE:EXT:website/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.typoscript">
```

and setup

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT:source="FILE:EXT:website/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript">
```

There are also other different ways to initial load TypoScript. See for example documentation here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/ExtensionConfiguration/Index.html

A description on how to load TypoScript without any root template in backend published here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Snippets/2017/Index.html#root-typoscript-without-database

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've already created an extension EXT:website to store your TypoScript, Fluid templates, etc. You should proceed as follows:

1) create in your extension a php file:

website/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php

```
<?php
  defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();
  call_user_func(function()
  {
  /**
   * Default Static TypoScript for website
   */
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
    'website',
    'Configuration/TypoScript',
    'My Provider extension for pages and content'
    );
  });
```

2) create two files:

- website/Configuration/constants.typoscript
- website/Configuration/setup.typoscript

3) You will be able then to add the these files using the "Include static (from extensions)" area of your TypoScript template.

Of course inside these files you can include other files or even folders, see the [documentation here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Includes.html)